# ZuulProxy is not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have created a spring boot application and it has one microservice. Now i want to directly access that microservice from browser which I have registered with eureka server.

[image]

Class **ServicesInfoClient** is one microservice and its config file is **serviceInfo.yml**.

ServiceInfoClient.java:

```
package com.myoldschool.manager.serviceClientInfo;

import com.myoldschool.manager.studentnames.StudentNameCountClient;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class ServicesInfoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "serviceInfo");
        SpringApplication.run(StudentNameCountClient.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getInfo")
    public String getServiceEndPoints(){
        return "all endpoints";
    }

}
```

serviceInfo.yml:

```
# Discovery Server Access
spring:
  application:
    name: services-info

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
    instance:
      hostname: localhost

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 4444   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

MyZuulProxyClient.java:

```
package com.myoldschool.manager.zuulservice;

import com.myoldschool.manager.ManagerApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyZuulProxyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "zuulService");
        SpringApplication.run(ManagerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

zuulService.yml:

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-service

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
    instance:
      hostname: localhost

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 5555   # HTTP (Tomcat) port

zuul:
  routes:
    services-info:
      path: /services-info/**
      serviceId: services-info
```

Now after running the application when i hit `http://localhost:1111/services-info/getInfo` it gives me this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Nov 22 16:34:12 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I have seen so many threads but none of them is working. So please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your EurekaServer microservice. You need to create Eureka Server as port:1111. After that, your microservices can register it.

Comment: I have just not posted its code here but i do have it and you can easily read that in the second line of my question that "microservice from browser which I have registered with eureka server".

Comment: Your request goes to Eureka Server which is port is 1111. However, you should send the request to your ZuulProxy. ZuulProxy will find your path and forward the request to a related microservice. Please edit port with 5555. http://localhost:5555/services-info/getInfo.